# How can I avoid GWT compilation by creating different modules?

Tags: gwt

We are using GWT for our application. Now as size of application grows, it is taking long time to compile, around 20-25 mins, which cause delay in development.

We have different modules, but currently all are in single application, as we have single entry point class.
So, is there any way that I divide those modules, and then import them in main module. So that compilation will happen only for module which has changes?

Comment: You don't have to rebuild all modules each build, only the one you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to recompile your application ?

Using SuperDevMode the recompilation is very fast. I almost never do a full compile of my GWT application. Only before release.

Why is your compilation taking so long ? 
How many permutations do you have ?

Try to reduce the number of permutations.

You can do this by not using GWTs i18n system but enrolling your own. 
And not compiling for all browsers.

I only compile for safari,gecko1_8 and ie10. I don't really want people using my app with IE9 and older so I don't compile for these browsers.

Some people even only compile safari and say that it works no problem on all browsers.

I never really understand people complaining about the compilation time as it is almost never needed. And can probably be reduced drasticly.